# Why isn't my variable going up by one?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just starting out with code, and I'm trying to make a *really* simple web page button. All I really want to do is for the page to show a number, and then when you click a button, the number goes up by one.

I'm trying to do this by using JavaScript and having a variable set to one, and then a function that increases the variable that runs whenever the button is pressed. Logically, I think what I've done should work, but it doesn't, so I'm definitely missing something.

Code is as follows: HTML -

```
<script>
document.write(demo)
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Increase Number</button>
```

and JavaScript -

```
var demo = 1;
function myFunction() {
demo++;
}
```

Is there something I need to put in the function to refresh the variable? At the moment, the page just loads as number 1 next to the button, nothing happens when I click.

Comment: you variable does go up - you are simply not calling `document.write()` again to write the new value to the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number does go up, but you already printed it by the time increment it. You can add a `span` tag to your HTML and use that to show the number in like this:

```js
var demo = 1;
function myFunction() {
    demo++;
    document.getElementById('num').innerText = demo;
}
```

```html
<span id="num">1</span>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Increase Number</button>
```

You use `document.getElementById('num')` to select the `span` tag and `.innerText` to set the number to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to print the variable every time you change it for the UI to be updated.

However, you should write it to a `span` or a `div` through `innerText` rather than using `document.write` to avoid overwriting the rest of HTML elements.

```js
var demo = 1;

document.getElementById("demo").innerText = demo;

function myFunction() {
  demo++;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = demo;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Increase Number</button>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure you're writing the variable to the document after it is incremented.

```
var demo = 1;
function myFunction() {
  demo++;
  document.write(demo);
}
```